# Error: Cannot read property 'cloneDeep' of undefined Angular 5

Tags: lodash

I get an error: "Cannot read property 'cloneDeep' of undefined"

- This worked before and broke after npm install
- There is no version mismatches of any library after npm install

Comment: Can you give more details of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the import statement worked for me.

Previously it is import _ from "lodash";
Now I changed it to import * as _ from "lodash"; which is working!